# Websocket + SSL(WSS) client implementation in C++

Tags: c++, node.js, ssl, websocket

I am trying to implement secure websocket connection (WSS) in c++ . I don't want to use any external library. I have the code which is working for normal (ws) connections. I want to add the support for HTTPS also. Can any body suggest me how to proceed in this.

Example: for normal ws connections:

GET /foo HTTP/1.1

Host: example.server.com

Upgrade: websocket

Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade

Sec-WebSocket-Key: dfGsdNhbXBsZSBub25REQ==

Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13.

The code which i have already is sending these type of requests, after creating normal socket and connected to server. In the same manner i want to do WSS also.
Please suggest me on how to do that.

Thanks,

VVK.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? If so, could you share a snippet please ?